Add separately-compiled complication data source to WFF
Can a separately-compiled complication data source (written in Java/Kotlin) be added to a WFF watchface bundle? If so, how?
Background: I have two deeply-coded scientific-oriented Kotlin watchfaces (SkyHalo and StarHalo) that need to be converted to WFF in order to be available in Wear 5.0, and there's no clear or documented path to do this.
The only possible path I see is to convert the watchface (minus the analog hands) to a SMALL_IMAGE complication data source, and use it in a WFF watchface as a background complication.
Assuming that this is possible, is this an approved way of doing this?

Good question! I am part of the developer team of the project 'Cronosurf Wave', a feature rich chronograph for Wear OS. We are facing the same problem. Our users are already asking if our watch face will run on new watches with Wear OS 5. And we have no answer yet. Google says the new format does not need code, but does that mean that it also does NOT allow for any code? How can we implement complex functions and full interactivity? I really hope Google reconsiders and allows users to install legacy watch faces on Wer OS 5 (perhaps with a warning about less optimal use of resources, etc.).

Exactly, go3d. I'm aware of two developers of popular Continuous Glucose Monitor-centric watchfaces for diabetics (supporting Dexcom and Libre) that have told me they're halting development/support for their watchfaces for the same reason. There must be some path forward, since this essentially kills all "smart" faces and restricts Wear to dumb (graphics-only) ones, which is a big step backward for the platform.

Absolutely agree! I hope you are right and there is a path forward. Otherwise, Google is shooting themselves on the foot. Let's hope there will be enough pushback from developers AND users. As a user, I certainly would not buy a watch with Wear OS 5 for now.

go3d, the old API (unfortunately) will not run on devices that comes with Wear OS 5 by default. Devices that are not by default wear os 5, but were updated to wear os 5 will support the old API, (In other words, watch 7 and any other released after, no matter the brand will not run the old. Watches released before the the Watch 7 will). I don't have any information about using code on watch face format, I want some info about it too, some of my watchfaces were built using it...

Thanks dect! You are correct. But Google's plan is to not allow watch faces to be updated or published any longer from 2025 on unless they are made with the WFF.

I didn't know that... too sad

In Android Studio, the Wear 5 (preview) emulator still runs non-WFF watchfaces. From all appearances, "WFF Only" is an artificial restriction; Wear 5 can still inherently run smart faces.  However, a StarHalo user who's received the Galaxy Ultra watch has related to me that the Play Store will not allow him to install either SkyHalo or StarHalo on it; the listings show that they are "incompatible," but can be installed on his other devices.

The root question that developers have been asking — and that so far Google has been silent on — is, can code be added to a WFF watchface bundle, and if so, how?

That's interesting. Yes, we are also getting many user emails saying they can not install our watch faces on their new Galaxy Watch 7 or Watch Ultra. I wonder if they would be able to install if I send them an apk file. And yes, we are also wondering if there will be some way to add code.

Still no solution, but here's some more information. A user says that be installed SkyHalo on an Ultra through the watch's Play Store, but it doesn't appear as anything selectable — and doesn't appear in the watch's app list (Settings / Apps & notifications / App info). He's permitted to uninstall and reinstall it, but still no change.  WTF is Wear doing?

Thanks for that input @NickEsposito. That doesn't sound good. So then perhaps installing a legacy watch face via adb would also lead to a watch face not being identified as such.

To provide some more links for all this: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces the red banner on that watch-face-overview guide says "... required ... for all new watch faces published on Google Play starting January 27, 2025."  It sounds to me like existing watch faces may be grandfathered in for an unknown amount of time, but nearly everything about WFF / requirements / timelines / docs is extremely ambiguous and full of gaps so I'm not at all confident about that.  Also e.g. Facer does not install non-WFF at all on my pixel watch 3, so.  YMMV.

I can 95% confirm that my solution works!

I created a Kotlin data source that performs some mathematical functions and uses the output to create a custom bitmap similar to what SkyHalo does with live data (minus the watchface's analog hands, digital time/date, and complication slots; we'll let WFF handle what it does best). Compiled this to an APK and loaded this onto the emulator.

I then created a WFF watchface containing analog hands, digital time/date, two standard circular complication slots, and one SMALL_IMAGE background complication that was the full size of the watchface. For this last complication, I locked the primarySource to the service name of the data source described in Step (1). This was compiled to an APK using the gradlew command line and loaded onto the emulator. It successfully displayed the Kotlin-coded data source in the background complication, essentially doing an end-run around WFF restrictions to create a smart watchface.


Several tests still need to be done before I write this all up. Using Android Studio I need to bundle the two signed APKs into an AAB, upload it to the Play Store (internal) and have someone with a new Wear 5.0 watch install and test it.
I also need to ensure that the complication updates in a timely manner, and that the data source correctly identifies watchface taps and ambient mode. In addition, the matter of preference-setting needs to be solved; the watchface method of long-pressing and selecting "settings" will only present the WFF-watchface settings, not the data source's settings.
But I'm optimistic that these can be solved.

Please update in the comments here to let us know how it goes!

Yes, this is what you can do today (but see below for outstanding issues):

Create a complication data source, as you normally would
In ComplicationSlot set the primaryProvider to your complication provider from (1), e.g. com.myapp/com.myapp.ComplicationService
Optionally, in ComplicationSlot set isCustomizable to false - if you wish this visualization not to be replaceable by the user, this can be useful.
As you point out, you can use something like a LARGE_IMAGE complication type if you wish to fill all or a significant portion of the screen.
If you are allowing the complication to be customizable, then you can just provide a configuration activity to configure it.
If not, you can always add a Launch element to your watch face which can launch a componentname/deeplink into your app (from where you can adjust settings which could be reflected in your complication data).

Challenge:
Your app (Activities, Complication Data Sources, etc...) must exist in one package, and your Watch Face Format code in another. The Watch Face Format bundle cannot contain any code if it is to pass Play validation.
This makes the use of primaryProvider problematic, as there is a chance that the data source isn't installed. The ComplicationSlot will then fall back to the system provider (e.g. Steps or whatever you specified).
There's no good solution to this challenge that I'm aware of at the moment, but I would love to hear more use cases for this - please let me know.
